# Set column to show 0 in JqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid. 
my function is --

```
   $("#grid").jqGrid({
      url: "/Log/GetLogs",
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'Get',
    colNames: ['LogID', 'Agency Billing Code', 'License    Number', 'Equipement Number', 'Year', 'Make', 'Model', 'Color', 'Begin Miles', 'End Miles'],
    colModel: [
        { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'ID', index: 'ID' },
                            { key: false, name: 'Year', index: 'Year', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'Make', index: 'Make', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'Model', index: 'Model', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'Color', index: 'Color', editable: false },
                { key: false, name: 'Miles', index: 'Miles', editable: true, cellvalue: "" },
    ],
      pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
    height: '100%',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'Log List',
    emptyrecords: 'No Records',
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "0"
    },
    autowidth: true,
    multiselect: false

});
```

When the grid loads, database is returning the value of "Miles" but I don't want to show that. I just want to show 0, and when I edit the miles values it should map to Miles in my object.
Please let me know how can I achieve that?
Thanks..

Comment: @Oleg can help you in this question

Comment: **Could you include an example of input data which you use to fill the grid? I mean one item of data returned by `url: "/Log/GetLogs"`?** Do you really use `repeatitems: false` format of data? In general one can solve your problem very easy by usage of `jsonmap` property in `colModel`. If you use really `repeatitems: false` format of data then `jsonmap: function () { return 0; }` in the column will solve your problem, but the property `id: "0"` of `jsonReader` seems strange. Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish what you need you need to have a formatter and unformatter for the miles column. You have not specified on how you will be editing the grid row(Inline, form Edit, custom...etc) but I created inline edit as an example for you.

Here is a the complete solution in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/233/) if you want to play with it. for editing just click the row and the miles will show its original value when on edit but show 0 on non edit mode. For more details on how formatting works see  [Here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter)

```
var mileformatter= function (cellval, options, rowObject) {
   return "<span data-val='"+cellval+"'>0</span>";
    }

    var mileUnFormat= function (cellvalue, options, cell) {
          return  $('span', cell).attr('data-val');
    }
            "use strict";
            var mydata = [
                    {ID:"1", Year: "1933", Make: "Nissan",Model:"Model1", Color: "White",Miles:1222},
                    {ID:"2", Year: "2008", Make: "Toyota",Model:"Model2" , Color: "Gray",Miles:3000},
                ];
            $("#list").jqGrid({
      data: mydata,
    datatype: "local",
    mtype: 'Get',
    colModel: [
        { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'ID', index: 'ID' },
         { key: false, name: 'Year', index: 'Year', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'Make', index: 'Make', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'Model', index: 'Model', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'Color', index: 'Color', editable: false },
       { key: false, formatter:mileformatter,unformat:mileUnFormat, name: 'Miles', index: 'Miles', editable: true, cellvalue: "" },
    ],
      pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
    height: '100%',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'Log List',
    emptyrecords: 'No Records',
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "0"
    },
    autowidth: true,
    multiselect: false,
    onSelectRow: function (id) {

             jQuery('#list').editRow(id, true);
             }


});
```

Here is an edited answer for what you are looking for and a new [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/258/) link to play with Note that I removed the unformatter and also added beforeSaveRow function.

```
var onEdit=false;

var mileformatter= function (cellval, options, rowObject) {
if(onEdit==true)
{
return cellval;
onEdit=false;
}
   return 0;
    }

            "use strict";
            var mydata = [
                    {ID:"1", Year: "1933", Make: "Nissan",Model:"Model1", Color: "White",Miles:1222},
                    {ID:"2", Year: "2008", Make: "Toyota",Model:"Model2" , Color: "Gray",Miles:3000},
                ];
            $("#list").jqGrid({
      data: mydata,
    datatype: "local",
    mtype: 'Get',
    colModel: [
        { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'ID', index: 'ID' },
         { key: false, name: 'Year', index: 'Year', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'Make', index: 'Make', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'Model', index: 'Model', editable: false },
        { key: false, name: 'Color', index: 'Color', editable: false },
       { key: false, formatter:mileformatter, name: 'Miles', index: 'Miles', editable: true, cellvalue: "" },
    ],
      pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
    height: '100%',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'Log List',
    emptyrecords: 'No Records',
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "0"
    },
    autowidth: true,
    multiselect: false,
    onSelectRow: function (id) {

             jQuery('#list').editRow(id, 
          {
                "keys": true,          
                oneditfunc: function () {

                },

                "successfunc": function () {
               alert('successfunc');
                },
                "url": null,
                "extraparam": {},
                "aftersavefunc": function () {
               alert('aftersavefunc');
                },
                "errorfunc": null,
                "afterrestorefunc": null,
                "restoreAfterError": true,
                "beforeSaveRow": function (options, rowid) {
                onEdit=true;
              jQuery("#list").saveRow(id, false);

                   return false;

                }
                });

       }


});
```

You can customize the SaveRow as follows and put the post url of your own.

```
 saveparameters = {
        "successfunc" : null,
        "url" : "yoururl",
            "extraparam" : {},
        "aftersavefunc" : null,
        "errorfunc": null,
        "afterrestorefunc" : null,
        "restoreAfterError" : true,
        "mtype" : "POST"
    }

    jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('saveRow',rowid,  saveparameters);
```

Comment: Thanks... this works.  when the grid loaded, but when I click to edit the value. It displays the value of the database. I don't want to display that. Is there the way to do that. When I click on the cell , still it will show 0 not the database value?

Comment: Is not that what you said "when I edit the miles values it should map to Miles in my object" ? can you clarify to me more. When do you ever want to use the database value? Make it more clear then I will update my answer.

Comment: on the screen I don't want database values. When user enter the values in miles, and I will save , it should map with Miles column in database.

Comment: So the grid will always display 0 in miles no matter what? Or should it display 0 when initially loaded But when the user edits the miles cell it should save it to db and it should display whatever is the edited value of mile ?

Comment: SO when grid is loaded first, it will display 0 , then when user entered the value , it should retain the entered value and when user clicks save, this value should save in the database for miles column.   Currently grid's column displays 0 when loads the data, when I click to edit it, it displays the database value. I don't want to display the value when I click for edit.

Comment: The saveRow does not save data in the database. Any idea?

Comment: Here is a link to help you understand save row http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing you I edited my answer.

Comment: After save values of the Endmiles become blank as onEdit = false. Is there way we can persist the values in the cell after save?